# writing text to another window

Tags: c#, text, output

I want to write text to the currently selected application but its writing junk and causing weird things to happen.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace i_allbwn
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            ActionWithChance.brif_allbwn();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class ActionWithChance
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

        public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; //Key down flag
        public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; //Key up flag

        public static void brif_allbwn()
        {
            argraffu(new String[] {
                    "line1",
                    "line2",
                    "line3",

            }
                    );
        }

        public static void allbwn(Byte[] Name)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing   " + (Char)Name[i]);
                keybd_event((Byte)Name[i], 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                keybd_event((Byte)Name[i], 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            }
        }
        public static void argraffu(String[] text)
        {
            foreach (String s in text)
            {
                allbwn(ToByteArray(s));
                keybd_event((Byte)'\r', 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                keybd_event((Byte)'\r', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            }
        }

        public static Byte[] ToByteArray(String StringToConvert)
        {

            Char[] CharArray = StringToConvert.ToCharArray();

            Byte[] ByteArray = new Byte[CharArray.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < CharArray.Length; i++)
            {

                ByteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(CharArray[i]);

            }

            return ByteArray;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is that other app console application ? How do you set keyboard focus to that other app ? And finally why that sleep on start ?

Comment: the other application is non applicable because it could be anything that accepts text input. by clicking on the app the sleep is just for testing purposes so that it doesnt instantly type the test text and finish before i click on the other app

Comment: use SendKeys, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My functions for doing it are like this:

```
    public const Int32 WM_CHAR = 0x0102;

    public void SendKeys(string message)
    {
        foreach (char c in message)
        {
            int charValue = c;
            IntPtr val = new IntPtr((Int32)c);
            SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CHAR, val, new IntPtr(0));
        }
    }
```

Basically what I'm doing is getting the handle of the application, e.g:

```
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")[0];
```

Then getting the handle with proc.MainModule.Handle()

Answer (score 1):

The Autoit library makes it really easy to interact with external windows.

Install the nuget package called `AutoItX.Dotnet`

Then it's just a matter of:

```
using AutoIt;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoItX.Run("notepad.exe", null);
        AutoItX.WinWait("Untitled - Notepad");
        AutoItX.ControlSend("Untitled - Notepad", "", "[CLASSNN:Edit1]", "testing");

        //ControlSend is the ideal way to send text, but you can also pretend text was typed into the keyboard:
        AutoItX.Send("howdy pilgrim");
    }
}
```